# Can't install updates after I failed to install tensorflow

Tags: apt, nvidia, updates, cuda, tensorflow

Ubuntu 20.04 x86_64
GeForce GT 730
Cuda 10.1 (checked before installing tensorflow, using `nvcc --version` worked, but now doesn't)

After I tried to install tensorflow and I failed first I couldn't reboot my PC because I installed the wrong nvidia driver. Then in recovery mode I installed the right one (390)
Now I can't sudo apt-get almost anything it give me error.

For example running `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnvidia-decode-390:i386 : Depends: libnvidia-compute-390:i386 (= 390.144-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-cuda-toolkit : Depends: nvidia-profiler (= 10.1.243-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: nvidia-cuda-dev (= 10.1.243-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: nvidia-opencl-dev (= 10.1.243-3) but it is not going to be installed or
                                opencl-dev
                       Depends: g++-8 but it is not going to be installed or
                                clang-8 but it is not going to be installed or
                                clang-7 but it is not going to be installed or
                                g++-7 but it is not going to be installed or
                                clang-6.0 but it is not going to be installed or
                                clang-5.0 but it is not installable or
                                clang-4.0 but it is not installable or
                                clang-3.9 but it is not installable or
                                clang-3.8 but it is not installable or
                                clang (< 1:9~) but it is not going to be installed or
                                g++-6 but it is not installable or
                                g++-5 but it is not installable or
                                g++-4.9 but it is not installable or
                                g++-4.8 but it is not installable
                       Recommends: nvidia-cuda-doc (= 10.1.243-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: nvidia-cuda-gdb (= 10.1.243-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: nvidia-visual-profiler (= 10.1.243-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: nsight-compute (= 10.1.243-3)
                       Recommends: nsight-systems (= 10.1.243-3)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Can't even install the updates the system proposes ->

[image: updates]

Please, help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: I would also `sudo apt update` to check you don't have errors.. A quick query shows `nvidia-cuda-doc | 10.1.243-3      | focal/multiverse  | all` is available for *focal* so are your sources correct; and I've assumed you've already tried what the message suggests (twice) you do to fix your issue.